# Suggestions for Grails .gitignore

Tags: git, grails

So far i've collected the following:

```
*.iws
*.war
.classpath
.DS_Store
.project
.settings
/*.launch
/*.tmproj
/out/**
stacktrace.log
test/reports
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update 5 years later (April 2014):

As mentioned in the other answers below, two sites are now able to provide good default .gitignore files, including for a Grails project.

- GitHub, when creating a new repo (based on the [github/gitignore project](https://github.com/github/gitignore)).
  => [`Grails.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Grails.gitignore)
- **[gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/)**
  => [Grails gitignore](http://www.gitignore.io/api/grails)

---

(Original answer, January 2009)

Only may be to add **`/web-app/WEB-INF`** to your list:here is [an full example](http://www.nabble.com/.gitignore-example-td19560531.html) of such a gitignore file.

```
# .gitignore for Grails 1.0.3

# web application files that are overwritten by "grails upgrade"
#  cf. GRAILS_HOME/scripts/Upgrade.groovy, target( upgrade )
/web-app/WEB-INF

# IDE support files that are overwritten by "grails upgrade"
#  cf. GRAILS_HOME/scripts/CreateApp.groovy, target( createIDESupportFiles )
# to be specific, you could replace "/*" below with your project name,
#  e.g. "foobar.launch" (no slash)
.classpath
.project
.settings
/*.launch
/*.tmproj

# logs
stacktrace.log
/test/reports

# project release file
*.war
```

---

Note, as [mentionned here](http://blog.sinequanon.net/2008/09/grails-gitignore/), that :

- `build.xml` is not part of that list, since grails won’t overwrite it.
- the eclipse dot files `.classpath`, `.project`, and `.settings` will also not be overwritten if they exist, but they can be ignored at first.
- for previous version of Grail, you would also have needed (at least) a line `/plugins/core`

Comment: Is it safe to ignore everything in the `/web-app/WEB-INF` folder?

Answer (score 66):

You can have the .gitignore file automatically generated by Grails using the following command:

```
grails integrate-with  --git
```

Grails 2.1.0 generated the following file content on my machine:

```
*.iws
*Db.properties
*Db.script
.settings
stacktrace.log
/*.zip
/plugin.xml
/*.log
/*DB.*
/cobertura.ser
.DS_Store
/target/
/out/
/web-app/plugins
/web-app/WEB-INF/classes
```

Answer (score 6):

IMHO, stuff like .DS_Store and *.tmproj should not be in the projects .gitignore, but rather in [your own userwide ignore-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5724455), as they aren't related to the project but just related to how *you* work in the repository.

Otherwise, an argument could be made to also include ignores for temporary files from Eclipse, vim, emacs, XCode, ...

Answer (score 4):

I'm very late to the game, but I came across this link for templates https://github.com/github/gitignore which has one for grails:  https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Grails.gitignore.  Hope it may be useful to anyone else who finds this page first by searching "git ignore for grails"

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Intelli J IDEA should also add these:

```
.idea
*.iml
*.iws
*.ipr
```

Comment: the .idea directory can be added to version control, indeed it should be.

Comment: I don't think so, since not every developer uses IDEA. Normally, project files should be kept IDE-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku also provides proposals for a `.gitgnore` file ([Getting Started with Grails on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-grails#check-in-to-git)):

```
*.iws
*Db.properties
*Db.script
.settings
.classpath
.project
eclipse
stacktrace.log
target
/plugins
/web-app/plugins
/web-app/WEB-INF/classes
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld
web-app/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld
```

We should bear all the suggestions from this thread together and create a common file. When working with the NetBeans IDE, then there are also some files that can be excluded (for example, the `nbprojects` folder).