# Can I make a user-specific gitignore file?

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

I want to change the gitignore, but not everyone on the team wants these changes. How can a user have their own specific git ignore file?

Comment: A very concise answer is actually provided in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description).

Answer (score 155, accepted):

For user-specific and repo-specific file ignoring you should populate the following file:

```
$GIT_DIR/info/exclude
```

Usually $GIT_DIR stands for:

```
your_repo_path/.git/
```

Comment: For those confused about the path: `your_repo/.git/info/exclude`. The file is formatted like a standard [.gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file.

Comment: If your file already contains unstaged changes you may need to run `git update-index --skip-worktree [<file>...]` (from https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/ignore-specific-file-changes-only-on-current-machine-in-git)

Answer (score 179):

You can create your own .gitignore using

```
git config --global core.excludesfile $HOME/.gitignore
```

Then put your desired entries in that file.

Comment: If you don't want it to be global, you can put your `.user_gitignore` file under repo's `.git` directory and add it with `git config core.excludesfile .git/.user_gitignore`

Comment: [Pro-tip from Tim Pope](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#faq): use `~/.cvsignore` because utilities like rsync will use this file as well.

Comment: @orad I think your comment deserves to be its own separate answer.

Comment: Take in account that orad's/Dave's suggestion will overwrite the default of `core.excludesfile` pointing to your global ignore file ie: `~/.gitignore`. If you want to preserve global exclusions and have repository specific exclusions as well, @grzuy's answer is the way to go

Comment: On Git for Windows, `$HOME/.gitignore` did not work correctly for me, but `~/.gitignore` did.

Comment: @orad If you don't want it to be global, just edit `$your_repo_path/.git/info/exclude`, which applies to that repo.

Answer (score 43):

In their .gitconfig:

```
[core]
    excludesfile = ~/.global_gitignore
```

That way, they can ignore certain types of files globally. Each user can have their own global ignore file.

Comment: You can access the `.gitconfig` by running `git config --local -e` in the repo you want

Answer (score 9):

For example, you want ignore `~/some/path/.idea` folder:

```bash
# 1. Add .idea to user specific gitignore file
echo .idea > ~/.gitignore

# 2. Add gitignore file to gitconfig
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Answer (score 8):

As indicated in [Atlassian's .gitignore tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/gitignore#personal-git-ignore-rules), you could also use your repo's `<repo>/.git/info/exclude` file that you can easily edit with any text editor. It works the same as `.gitignore`.

I could easily ignore my intelliJ files, personal dockerfiles and stuff only I need to work with.

Comment: Yes!  Edit the `exclude` file to get *repo specific* ignore of files or file patterns.  Great for scripts that I want to use for that repo and _store_ in that repo, but don't want committed to the project at large, and don't want cluttering the `.gitignore` file that is shared by everybody.

Comment: Careful with this one. I've had two occasions now where git ends up split-brained about files in the `.git/info/exclude` folder and refuses to let me do most operations (because it thinks the files are dirty) and refuses to let me restore them (because it thinks the files are to be ignored).

Even removing the files from `exclude` doesn't resolve the issue -- I had to discard the entire folder and re-clone the project from a remote.

Answer (score 5):

## Global (user) scope ignore

Per [gitignore Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), a user-level `excludesfile` default exists without editing `git config --global core.excludesfile`:

> Patterns which a user wants Git to ignore in all situations (e.g., backup or temporary files generated by the user’s editor of choice) generally go into a file specified by `core.excludesFile` in the user’s `~/.gitconfig`. Its default value is $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is either not set or empty, $HOME/.config/git/ignore is used instead.

So one only need create (and populate) the relevant file, usually `$HOME/.config/git/ignore` (and possibly path):

```bash
if [ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}" ] ;
then 
    echo "XDG_CONFIG_HOME unset or empty, try \$HOME" ;
    if [ -z "${HOME+x}" ]
    then
        echo "Variables for default not set"
        echo "use explicit \`git config --global core.excludesfile EXCLUDES_FILE\`"
    else
        echo using \$HOME
        mkdir -p "$HOME/.config/git" && touch "$HOME/.config/git/ignore"
    fi
else
    echo using \$XDG_CONFIG_HOME
    mkdir -p "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git" && touch "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore"

fi
```

Caveat: This configuration is implicit rather than explicit. Consider setting `git config --global core.excludesfile` to the chosen file, even if it is a default.

## Repo scope user-specific ignore

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file.

So from the root of the repo, edit `.git/info/exclude`

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer. `~/.config/git/ignore` is the default at the user level (for *NIX systems). If you want to override it, then you can add an explicit path to your config file via `git config --global core.excludesfile $whatever`