# How not to break git(hub) projects and still be useful

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I like the idea behind open-source projects (packages, libraries, cms, etc.) and I want to contribute on projects I find interesting (and can help on tasks, bugs, features).

I've been using git for quite some time but to track projects I work on my own. Never had the chance to join a team and develop something together. (I know it's a must to you use vcs).

Here's the scenario, followed by my *actual* question:

1. Found a composer package which I need and like (a wrapper for some service's API written in PHP) and wanted to improve something (a new feature steam released).
2. I downloaded the github client (which is pretty strightforward way to contribute to projects on GitHub). Cloned the repository.
3. Then I opened my favorite IDE (which is PHPStorm as of date) and added the cloned repo as a project.
4. Changed what I wanted and went to the github client again.
5. The client showed me the changes and has added to the changelist the `.idea` files from my IDE.

So here's the question:

Do I have to add those file to the ignore list (1) or should I select the option to "discard those changes"(2)?

The problems I see:

In the first case I will update the `.gitignore` file which might be redundant if none of the collaborators use PHPStorm or any other IntelliJ IDE.

In the second case I will have to do those actions everytime I want to commit something.

Can you tell me how it's done in the more experienced world?

Comment: You have a local .gitignore you can use

http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724455/can-i-make-a-user-specific-gitignore-file) and [the .gitignore documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for how to set up a custom gitignore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either add those IDE-files to the projects .gitignore file, or if you don't want to add your local ignorable files to the project you could keep your own global .gitignore file.

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

Create the ~/.gitignore file and add `.idea/`