Git: how do I ignore a folder and everyting in it?
This is my .gitignore, located in the root Git repo folder:
.vscode/

My .vscode is also located in the root Git repo folder.
When I do git status I get:
modified:   .vscode/launch.json
How do I ignore a Git .vscode folder and everyting in it?
I tried .vscode/**, .vscode/*, nothing works.

Git will never ignore versioned items. You may need to remove launch.json first.

Adding the line below to .gitignore should suffice to ignore that folder.
.vscode/

You may have already added this folder to the index so it's still showing in git status. So after adding it to .gitignore exclusions, you need to remove it from the staging area (in case you had added the folder with git add). You may run:
git rm -r --cached .vscode/


I don't plan to commit the changes to .gitignore, it should be just for me locally. Does the line you provided keep it all local?

@Danijel See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724455/can-i-make-a-user-specific-gitignore-file

@Danijel yes it does keep it all local: it makes the exclusion work at the moment you save .gitignore, while also showing you could add .gitignore to a commit. git status will keep showing .gitignore there due to the line you added, so you will need to avoid adding it to your next commit. This also means you can't run the simple git add . command since it will add .gitignore

@Danijel If you do not plan to commit the modified .gitignore, you better edit .git/info/exclude instead. This is always local.

create a .gitignore file (a file called .gitignore) in the project folder.
In the file write .vscode/

Then run git rm -r --cached .vscode
Then commit and push.
